# How to position one element over other in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am using a `Grid` view and have defined two elements, `WebBrowser` and an `Image`, to be contained inside that `Grid`.

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Background="Black">
            <phone:WebBrowser Name="WebView"
                              IsScriptEnabled="True"
                              Grid.Row="0"
                              IsGeolocationEnabled="True"
                              ScriptNotify="webView_ScriptNotify"
                              NavigationFailed="webView_NavigationFailed"
                              Navigated="webView_Navigated"
                              Navigating="webView_Navigating"
                              VerticalAlignment="Top"
                              LoadCompleted="WebView_LoadCompleted"
                              Canvas.Top="0"
                              Canvas.Left="0"
                              Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=LayoutRoot}"
                              Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=LayoutRoot}">
            </phone:WebBrowser>
            <Image  Name="StartLogo" Source="/Assets/StartScreen3.png" Stretch="None" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></Image>
        </Grid>
```

I want the image to come over WebBrowser view at bottom. But with WebBrowser visible Image is not showing up. Can someone help me to fix it. I don't want to resize the WebBrowser to some smaller height.

And also how does order of defining elements inside a Grid affects the view?

**EDIT:**

I used `Canvas` to contain both of these. Works fine now.

Comment: You should set the image to collapsed when you don't need it otherwise it will catch all the touch events on its area

Comment: I want image to be there always.

Comment: How big is the image?

Comment: I mean Size in pixels

Comment: Image is of 480x75. But I have used Canvas now to get both work. Works fine now. thanks

Answer (score 0):

the image should be show as apparently nothing is wrong with your code. It might be that image color and opened web page color is same that is why image might not be visible. or some issue with image path or build action of the image.

the last UI element will be on top all other UI elements in the gird. as per your xaml image control will be top of the webbrowser control but at the bottom of the grid.

Comment: Hey. I changed the order of defined elements inside grid and defined image first and WebBrowser second. Now both are showing up but WebBrowser became unresponsive now. I mean its visible but control is not with the browser. Its with the Image. How can I make both work at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

There is no mistake in your code but still if you are facing this Problem
Try this:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <phone:WebBrowser Name="WebView"
                              IsScriptEnabled="True"
                              Grid.Row="0"
                              Grid.RowSpan="2"
                              IsGeolocationEnabled="True"
                              ScriptNotify="webView_ScriptNotify"
                              NavigationFailed="webView_NavigationFailed"
                              Navigated="webView_Navigated"
                              Navigating="webView_Navigating"
                              VerticalAlignment="Top"
                              LoadCompleted="WebView_LoadCompleted"
                              Canvas.Top="0"
                              Canvas.Left="0"
                              Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=LayoutRoot}"
                              Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=LayoutRoot}">
            </phone:WebBrowser>
            <Image  Name="StartLogo" Source="/Assets/ApplicationIcon.png" Stretch="None" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1"></Image>
        </Grid>
```

The Order of Defining UI Elements Overlaps the Previos Defined Control

Comment: Hey. I changed the order of defined elements inside grid and defined image first and WebBrowser second. Now both are showing up but WebBrowser became unresponsive now. I mean its visible but control is not with the browser. Its with the Image. How can I make both work at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

If you right click the object in design mode you should be able to order the objects on the application page?

Comment: out of interest where abouts on the web browser control are you trying to display the image and for what purpose?